# Homebrew Installed But Also Not Installed

Tags: ruby, operating-system, homebrew, osx-mavericks

When I tried to install homebrew I got this error. It started simple but then I was perplexed.

```
cjbrigna$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
Password:
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Could not resolve host: github.com
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

No problem, github was down for a little while. So I tried again later.

```
cjbrigna$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Which makes me think I have homebrew.

```
cjbrigna$ brew help
-sh: brew: command not found
```

Well clearly I didn't have homebrew.

```
cjbrigna$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

Well now I can't install or uninstall homebrew. This makes no sense. What did I do wrong? I appreciate any help.

Comment: what does `ls -ld /usr/local/.git` print?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  11 cjbrigna  wheel  374 Oct  6 16:04 /usr/local/.git

Comment: I would try: `cd /usr/local/.git && git pull` After that I would try the uninstall script one more time.

Comment: `$ cd /usr/local/.git && git pull
remote: Counting objects: 294789, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Total 294789 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 294760
Receiving objects: 100% (294789/294789), 54.07 MiB | 11.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (221658/221658), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>`

Comment: `If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master`

Answer (score 1):

You can finish the [install process](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/install#L218) manually:

```
cd /usr/local
git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then ensure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`. If it is you should then be able to run e.g. `brew help` to check that Homebrew is installed.